# Convert div to table; extract div or table

Tags: html, perl, parsing, html-table

I parsed a website containing main content in a table using HTML::TableExtract. That works fine. Another website has the main content in div tags stored.

I would like to:

1. convert div to table using HTML::TableExtract
   or
2. parsing the div tags like HTML::TableExtract

The major goal is not to find/parse the HTML file with classes and tags, because the website is changing their layout (html classes) in little ways almost every 
week, so the parsing would would slightly fail at some points. Using HTML::TableExtract and parse with coords of the table, they would be much more independency.

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: I don't see how you would translate divs to a table. Where are the rows, where are the columns? How can you have a coordinate with a div layout? It would be easier if you show us those websites.

Comment: div2table does not work at all? is there somehow another way of parsing, building json/xml out of html, using a module liek HTML::TableExtract  for extracting html5 files?

Comment: download the source http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MSISK/HTML-TableExtract-2.13/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm make copy, rename to DivExtract and replace 'table' 'tr' and 'td' with divs. The problem would be how to map which div is the 1st level (table), 2nd level (tr - row) or 3rd or more (td)

Comment: Thanks a ton. Is there any other idea so far?